# Magento2.2.5 How to access Magento Log file for Web API?

Tags: magento-2.2.5, webapi

we use the Magento API to update our warehouse system when we receive orders and then update Magento again with inventory updates from our warehouse system. However, we recently had an order that gave the below error and we are not sure how or where to access the API error log?

> "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report
> ID: webapi-5c644d10f0e26"

I have looked in `var/log` as well as in the `var/report` and I don't see any API folder or log file with API referenced in the name??

I have magento 2.2.5

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just run the below command in magento root directory, it will show that log file location.

```
grep -r "Report ID: webapi-5c644d10f0e26" var/
```

> **Note:** Change the above report id as per your error report - e.g) Report ID: webapi-xxxxxxxxxxx

Up to my mind it is in `exception.log` file and find the line with the content `webapi-5c644d10f0e26` for the detailed report.

Comment: How can I find the log using only the web interface?  I do not have access to the underlying OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can check exception.log for the same and find the report id "webapi-5c644d10f0e26"

> [2022-09-22 04:43:55] report.CRITICAL: Report ID:
> webapi-632be80baacc4; Message: Notice: Trying to get property
> 'itemsCsvP' of non-object in
> /var/www/html/app/code/vendor/ApiConnect/Model/GetMultiProductStock.php on line 55 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID:
> webapi-632be80baacc4; Message: Notice: Trying to get property
> 'itemsCsvP' of non-object in
> /var/www/html/app/code/vendor/ApiConnect/Model/GetMultiProductStock.php on line 55 at
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208,
> Exception(code: 0): Notice: Trying to get property 'itemsCsvP' of
> non-object in
> /var/www/html/app/code/vendor/ApiConnect/Model/GetMultiProductStock.php on line 55 at
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"}
> []

Answer (score 0):

It should be present in var/log/system.log.