# Can not get all SOAP services in Postman

Tags: magento2, soap, error-message, postman

I can not get all SOAP services in Postman.
when I send: http://magento2.url/soap?wsdl_list=1
I get the following response: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Base on the message in the response

> Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID:`

It looks like you have an internal Magento issue.

You can check Magento log files and find what is went wrong. Hint grep for `Report ID: webapi-604...686`.
And take a look at this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/261670/94440.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is wrong. The correct one is `http://magento2.url/soap/all?wsdl_list=1`

As per https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/soap/soap-web-api-calls.html:

> If you want an overview to all the available Web Services, use the following URL format to get a list of all SOAP Services: http://<magento.host>/soap/all?wsdl_list=1